# How can I separate these two lists after Console.WriteLine?

Tags: c#, console-application, line-breaks

I'm guessing this is something simple that I am overlooking but I have two lists that write to the console after sorting. How can I put one or 2 line breaks between the two lists to separate their output.

```
foreach (var number in map.OrderBy(i => i.Key))
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}

foreach (var color in map.OrderBy(c => c.Value == ColorType.White ?
                            0 : c.Value == ColorType.Yellow ? 1 : 2))
{
    Console.WriteLine(color);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

With this both lists are together after the Console.Readline();

Here is what the results look like now.

```
[92, Yellow]
[94, Yellow]
[97, Red]
[98, White]
[99, Red]
[100, White]
[100, White]
[43, White]
[14, White]
[59, White]
[8, White]
```

This is what I'd like it to look like:

```
[92, Yellow]
[94, Yellow]
[97, Red]
[98, White]
[99, Red]

[100, White]
[100, White]
[43, White]
[14, White]
[59, White]
[8, White]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the `'\n'` character. Or call `WriteLine()` with no arguments.

Comment: It's kind of weird that you know how to use LINQ but don't know how to print an empty string...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, very simple question I know. I wasn't searching correctly so it was making it difficult to find this solution. I was looking for how to insert a line break and it wasn't providing me an accurate result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just call

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

before the second `foreach`.